# Android Notification.BigTextStyle behavior

Tags: android, notifications, phonegap-cli

I have observed the following behavior when I create a notification with

```
Notification.setContextText("Teaser text.  Read more...");
Notification.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText("full text ..."));
```

- When the notification appears at the top of the list (or is the only notification) I see the whole of "full text" wrapped onto multiple lines as required.
- When there are other notifications above this one I see "Teaser text.  Read more...".
- If I leave out the BigTextStyle bit above and simply issue `setContentText("full text...")` the full text appears partially and does not wrap around.

Is this the expected behavior?  Can it somehow be modified so as to always - i.e. when the notification is not at the top of the list - show the big text - or get ContentText to wrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct. Only the topmost notification is expanded by default, however the user can always expand any notification (through a two finger swipe down or one finger hold and swipe down). There's no way to programmatically always make your notification expanded or programmatically expand it.

Comment: Is it possible to make pending action for expand ?! Click event is "user request" gesture ...

Comment: @NikolaLukic - no, sorry.